# JQuery / Canvas / Javascript … What can I use to move or rotate image with the mouse into a div?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, rotation, move

I'm working on a interactive website which uses PHP/Javascript/JQuery.
On a page, I want to propose to a visitor to move and/or rotate images with his mouse in order to create a new composition (like the following illustration) and save the result as a JPG…

[image: move and rotate images into a div]

… but I really don't know how to do that… Can you help me?

Many thanks.

Comment: What's your browser support going to be looking like? If you're using CSS3 and new browsers you can move things around fairly easily.

Comment: For the moment, I try to stay as compatible as possible.
For instance: I'm using ["cropzoom"](http://code.google.com/p/cropzoom/) which is supported by IE6+.

Answer (score 2):

For something that simple I'd use SVG and not Canvas.

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) is one of the fine libraries for SVG.

Canvas libraries that could do something simple like this are [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) and [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/)

Normally I don't advocate libraries but if that's all the app is going to do then it will save you loads of time.

Comment: FabricJS seems to be appropriate to solve my issue even if working in SVG would be more interesting (I don't find any demo of what I want on the Raphael website). FabricJS offers also cross-browser compatibility (except, of course, IE versions below 9). Maybe with exCanvas can I increase the browser compatibility ? Nevertheless, thank you very very much for your answer.

Comment: I contacted my webhosting and I can't use FabricJS due to the python's version… Does anything else exist like FabricJS?

Answer (score 0):

So let me be clear **this will be really hard**.

If you use Canvas, you can export it to be PNG with a small server-side script.

There are other people that have done things like this, [Lucid Chart](http://www.lucidchart.com/) uses DOM elements to move stuff around and draws them with Canvas. I'm not sure how they do they exporting.

Here's a little bit about how you can do it if you use Canvas for the whole thing.

On the PHP side:

```
// requires php5
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

On the JS side (using jQuery):

```
var c  = document.getElementById("yourCanvas");
var png = canvas.toDataURL();
$.post("postimg.php", {img: png}, function() {
    console.log("saved your thing");
});
```

I wrote a blog post about this last year, but only included the PHP side:

http://j-query.blogspot.com/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Jamund but I think Simon's answer is closer way to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to make use of the [svg-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) project, possibly tweaking it to better suit your needs if all you want is basic transforms.